# How to navigate between Tabs while clicking the Back button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

There are three tabs in my Project :

1.Home

2.Search

3.Profile

While i'm in the Profile Tab when i'm clicking the Device's BackButton i need to switch to the Home Tab.

In my Project i have used the BottomBar from this link

https://asyncawait.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/bottom-menu-for-xamarin-forms-android/

Comment: There is no easy way to do this except create your own stack and push the navigation ie; the tab index and then when user taps on the back button handle it and pop the stack and reset the tab index.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code in `OnBackButtonPressed()` event in profile page.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        var masterPage = this.Parent as TabbedPage;
        masterPage.CurrentPage = masterPage.Children[0];
        masterPage.CurrentPage.Focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Then might be you have to update `TabbedPage` to BottomBarPage`.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            var masterPage = this.Parent as BottomBarPage;
            masterPage.CurrentPage = masterPage.Children[0];
            masterPage.CurrentPage.Focus();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: masterPage is null

Comment: Its not working it shows The type or namespace name 'BottomNavigationBar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Instead of that i have used by TabbedHome in which i have added Child pages that too returns null

Comment: You have to add NameSpace of plugin which you are using for Android.